# How do I hide Task of Task?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

Consider the following method:

```
private async Task<Task<Response>> SendAsync(string data)
{
    this.Tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();

    await this.Stream.WriteAsync(...);
    await this.Stream.FlushAsync();

    return this.Tcs.Task;
}
```

I have an async method, which I expect to return `Task<Response>`. But since I want to return `TaskCompletionSource<Response>` (which gets set elsewhere, so I can't await it here), I have to actually return `Task<Task<Response>>` instead.

In the calling code, I have two ways of dealing with it while hiding this ugliness from the outside of the class. Assuming the response is not important and can be ignored, I can simply return a `Task`:

```
public Task GetAsync(string key)
{
    return this.SendAsync("GET " + key);
}
```

On the other hand, if I want the response, I have to use this ugly `await await` to make it work:

```
public async Task<Response> GetAsync(string key)
{
    return await await this.SendAsync("GET " + key);
}
```

Is there a better way of dealing with this, i.e. returning the `Task<Response>` from `SendAsync()` without exposing a `Task<Task<Response>>` outside the class, and at the same time not using the `await await`?

Comment: In `SendAsync`, instead of `return this.Tcs.Task;` why not `return await this.Tcs.Task;` to get clean `Task<Response>` return type?

Comment: This, indeed, is a strange looking `async` method, but since you asked about unwrapping `Task<Task<T>>`, that's exactly what the `Unwrap` extension method (defined in `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions`) does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to use a `TaskCompletionSource` **inside** an async method. Usually you either do the one or the other.

But if you must then forget returning the `TaskCompletionSource.Task`. Simply await the task like you do the rest of the async methods (`WriteAsync` and `FlushAsync`) and change the method to return `Task<Response>`:

```
private async Task<Response> SendAsync(string data)
{
    this.Tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();

    await this.Stream.WriteAsync(...);
    await this.Stream.FlushAsync();

    return await this.Tcs.Task;
}
```

That way the async method returns a task that gets completed when there's a `Response` so you only need to `await SendAsync("...")` once.

Comment: I actually didn't do this because I wanted to return the Task as is, without waiting for it to complete. But I suppose that to the caller, it won't make a difference, right?

Comment: @Gigi exactly. If your method is async anyway, then awaiting inside the method means the caller gets back a task that represents the entire async method. You don't block the method synchronously. The task is returned to the caller when you await `WriteAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @i3arnon is a good solution, however another solution is to use the `Unwrap` extension method.

The [`TaskExtensions.Unwrap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap(v=vs.110).aspx) method is designed for converting a `Task<Task<TResult>>` into a `Task<TResult>` and can be used as follows:

```
public Task<Response> GetAsync(string key)
{
    return this.SendAsync("GET " + key).Unwrap();
}
```

Any result, exception or cancellation will be propagated correctly to the resulting `Task<TResult>`.